# JQuery dialog close and reload page

Tags: jquery

does anybody please know how I should close the dialog with fade effect and reload the page only after it is closed. Unfortunately location.reload occurs immediately without waiting for dialog being closed.

```
function show_dialog_ok()
{
$("#dialog_ok").text("Your message was sent");
$("#dialog_ok").dialog({
  hide: {effect: "fade", duration: 2000}, modal: true
});

setTimeout(function() { $("#dialog_ok").dialog('close'); }, 2000);

location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about reloading at the same time you're closing the dialog, inside the timeOut

```
function show_dialog_ok() {
    $("#dialog_ok").text("Your message was sent");
    $("#dialog_ok").dialog({
        hide: {effect: "fade", duration: 2000}, modal: true
    });

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#dialog_ok").dialog('close'); 
        location.reload();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete callback to call realod after animation is complete:

```
function show_dialog_ok()
{
    $("#dialog_ok").text("Your message was sent");
    $("#dialog_ok").dialog({
      hide: {
        effect: "fade", 
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
      }, modal: true
    });

    setTimeout(function() { $("#dialog_ok").dialog('close'); }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried both, the first one still reloads it immediately and the second one hide effect works but it does not reload the page at all :-(

Comment: I yet tried to put alert function instead of reload and it does not alert anything, so it seems to be ignoring complete at all, any other ideas please? I yet checked if all brackets are properly closed and looks fine.

Comment: Resolved, I had to add setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); },4000); in the end